# I have query about TeamSpeak3

Tags: teamspeak

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ71N.jpg)
I have installed TeamSpeak3 and while launching the app, I receive the Following error: " the procedure entry point free could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Program Files\TeamSpeak3 Client\Qt5Qml.dll ". How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This might no be the correct place to post this kind of question, but nonetheless here's my answer:

I also had this error once, as I remember, and a reinstall fixed this for me. Hopefully for you as well.